# Universal image Loader displaying different image in loading time in android

Tags: android

I am using Universal Image loader to display listview Image from web. But in loading time one image item shows other image item . after sometime when it fully loaded it shows the exact image . It sometimes seems very awkward-- One man shows another man's pic. Thanks in advance. 
My adapter code :

public class EmployeeAdapter extends BaseAdapter implements Filterable {

```
    private ArrayList<EmployeeObj> mOriginalValues; // Original Values
    private ArrayList<EmployeeObj> mDisplayedValues; // Values to be
    private ImageLoader imageLoader; // displayed
    LayoutInflater inflater;

    public EmployeeAdapter(Context context,
            ArrayList<EmployeeObj> mProductArrayList) {
        this.mOriginalValues = mProductArrayList;
        this.mDisplayedValues = mProductArrayList;
        inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        imageLoader = ImageLoader.getInstance();
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mDisplayedValues.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return mDisplayedValues.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    private class ViewHolder {
        LinearLayout llContainer;
        TextView employeeName, employeeDesignation;
        Button callButton;
        ImageView imageView;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView,
            ViewGroup parent) {

        ViewHolder holder = null;

        if (convertView == null) {

            holder = new ViewHolder();
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.employee_row, null);
            holder.llContainer = (LinearLayout) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.searchListView);
            holder.employeeName = (TextView) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.listTitle);
            holder.employeeDesignation = (TextView) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.listDesignation);

            holder.callButton = (Button) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.listButton);

            holder.imageView = (ImageView) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.listImage);

            convertView.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        String addEmployeeName = mDisplayedValues.get(position)
                .getEmployeeName();

        if (addEmployeeName.length() >= 20) {
            addEmployeeName = addEmployeeName.substring(0, 20);
            addEmployeeName = addEmployeeName + ".....";
        }
        holder.employeeName.setText(addEmployeeName);

        holder.employeeDesignation.setText(mDisplayedValues.get(position)
                .getEmployeeDesignation());

        // holder.employeeMobile.setText("01722761395");
        // holder.employeeDesignation.setText(mDisplayedValues.get(position)
        // .getEmployeeDesignation());


        holder.callButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                // Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Done",
                // Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                // int position=(Integer)adapter.
                // Log.e("position==",position+"");
                pos = position;

                dialog.show();
            }
        });

        String path = mDisplayedValues.get(position).getImagePath();

        if (path.length() <= 5) {

        } else {

            DisplayImageOptions options = new DisplayImageOptions.Builder()
                    .cacheOnDisc().cacheInMemory().build();
            imageLoader.displayImage(path, holder.imageView, options);
        }
        convertView.setBackgroundColor(position % 2 == 0 ? Color
                .parseColor("#ffffff") : Color.parseColor("#ffffff"));
        return convertView;
    }
```

Comment: please share some code!

Comment: show your adapter code

Comment: Brother I have edited the question with adding the adapter code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is due to the fact that UIL reuses imageView's when they are not seen anymore. Let's say your screen can dispay 3 images at the same time, when the top or bottom image is out of the screen (depending if you scroll up or down) that image view will be reused to load the next image you will be displaying.

So if you have configured UIL to be loading 3 image simultaneously by the time the new image is loaded you will se the old one because the imageView is reused. So the best thing to do would be to set a number of loaded image big enough so that UIL has the time to load the new ones before they are seen.

Don't know if I was clear enough. Tell me if you need more explanation.

**EDIT:**

You need to set the pool size by calling `threadPoolSize()` to set the maximum number of images to be loaded.

```
public class testApplication extends Application {
    Context mContext;

    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        mContext = getApplicationContext();
        DisplayImageOptions options = new DisplayImageOptions.Builder()
                .delayBeforeLoading(0)
                .resetViewBeforeLoading(true)
                .cacheInMemory(true)
                .cacheOnDisk(true)
                .bitmapConfig(Bitmap.Config.RGB_565)
                .imageScaleType(ImageScaleType.EXACTLY)
                .build();

        ImageLoaderConfiguration config = new ImageLoaderConfiguration.Builder(mContext)
                .denyCacheImageMultipleSizesInMemory()
                .defaultDisplayImageOptions(options)
                .diskCacheExtraOptions(480, 320, null)
//                .memoryCacheSize(41943040)
                .threadPoolSize(10)
                .build();

        ImageLoader.getInstance().init(config);
    }
}
```

In the example above I load 10 images (even if 10 are not show at the same time).

Another thing, if you really don't want the old image to show before the new one is loaded you can set `.resetViewBeforeLoading(true)` in your `DisplayImageOptions`.

Last. If you get an `out of memory error`, [read this](https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader/wiki/Useful-Info)  (point 4)

Comment: Thank you for your explanation . I realized it . But How can i set the number of image to be loaded ?

Comment: .resetViewBeforeLoading(true) is perfect solution for me. thanks buddy...